# Not able to add specific custom font in xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, custom-font

I am trying to add DINCondensedBold font in Xcode 7.2.

I followed the tutorial `http://refactr.com/blog/2012/09/ios-tips-custom-fonts/`

and I was able to add 4 fonts, out of 5, except DINCondensedBold. I tried to add .ttf .otf but was not able to do it.

1) I added my font to add in target.
2) I added the name of file in info.plist
3) I made sure that .ttf file is added in "copy bundle resources"

I am not sure why this particular font is not working. I tried to download font file for same font , from different websites but still I am stuck.

Please help someone.

Comment: http://refactr.com/blog/2012/09/ios-tips-custom-fonts/ perfect answer. you miss somthing

Comment: Please refer to this: http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/, you must be missing out something

Comment: Sorry all. It was just not printing in the list of all fonts I printed in Xcode. But It is working when I use this font in label.